# ApexCharts: radar chart fill and stroke

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Using ApexCharts, I have the following options

```
    this.chartOptions = {
      xaxis: {
        labels: {
          show: true,
          style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontWeight: 700
          },
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        show: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [8, 7, 10, 8, 16, 9, 10, 5]
        },
        {
          data: [9, 15, 10, 10, 15, 11, 14, 10]
        },
        {
          data: [8, 15, 9, 10, 15, 11, 13, 10]
        },
      ]
      chart: {
        type: 'radar',
        toolbar: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      markers: {
        size: 0,
        strokeWidth: 0
      },
      fill: {
         colors: ['#157FF8', '#16B264', '#FF576F']
      },
      stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: [6, 1, 1],
        colors: ['#157FF8', 'transparent', 'transparent']
      },
      plotOptions: {
        radar: {
          polygons: {
            fill: {
              colors: ['#fff']
            }
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      }
    };
```

I would expect that the strokes of my graphs would be 6 for the first series and 1 for the next two, but they're all 6.

How do I set the stroke widths of a radar chart with multiple data entries?

Comment: Looks like bug but if you do `width: [6],` it kind of works like you wantd (at least in my case).

Comment: I saw in the documentation that passing an array to width is only possible for line and area charts. So when passing an array to stroke width for a radar chart it only takes the first index. I guess it's not possible to have multiple stroke widths in a radar chart.